# PrimeNG- p-draggable-enter class not working

Tags: angular, angular7, primeng

I have the following `listbox` on my `Angular Component` item which is a sortable list with a `pDraggable` and `pDroppable` method:

```
<p-listbox [options]="listsOptions">
   <ng-template let-ratecard let-index="index" pTemplate="item">
      <div pDraggable="optionDrag" pDroppable="optionDrag" (onDragStart)="onDragStart(index)" (onDrop)="onDrop(index)" (onDrag)="onDrag($event, index)">
       <span class="option-class">{{option.Name}}</span>
         </div>
        </ng-template>
 </p-listbox>
```

My problem here is that I need to add a hover effect to each item list when the dragging is hovering each one.

The documentation mentions a `p-draggable-enter` class to add any effect on a droppable area, which in my case is any item on the list.

My problem here is that this class is not doing any changes.

I've added the following on my .css file:

```
.p-draggable-enter {
  background: red !important;
}
```

And I'm not seeing any changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you been able to get it to work? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to set first a custom class on your `pDroppable` item e.g. `drop-column`:

```
<div class="col-12 md:col-6 drop-column" pDroppable="products" (onDrop)="drop()">
  ...
```

Then, set the CSS like this:

```
.drop-column {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-color .2s;

    &.p-draggable-enter {
      border-color: var(--primary-color); 
    }
}
```

That will change the border color when the item enters the droppable.

Code extracted from the ['Source' tab on Drag & Drop documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/dragdrop) example.